# Wie schreibt man "Nullen" und "Einsen" als Zahlzeichen (0en und 1en?)

Tags: spelling, numbers

In Texten über Computer bzw. Binärzahlen kommen oft Formulierungen wie "eine Binärzahl besteht aus Nullen und Einsen" vor. Manchmal wäre es praktischer oder übersichtlicher, wenn man statt der ausgeschriebenen Wörter "Nullen" bzw. "Einsen" das Zahlzeichen 0 bzw. 1 verwenden könnte, aber geht das im Plural und wenn ja, wie?

Im Englischen ist es üblich, z.b. "a string of 0s and 1s" zu schreiben, aber "0en und 1en" sieht im Deutschen merkwürdig und ungewohnt aus. Im Duden finde ich keine passende Regel oder Beispiele.

Answer (score 5):

Ich glaube, das ist im Deutschen nicht gebräuchlich. Die folgenden beiden Varianten sind üblich:

> Eine Binärzahl besteht aus den Ziffern 0 und 1.
>
> Eine Binärzahl besteht aus Nullen und Einsen.

Comment: es ist im Deutsch **nicht** gebräuchlich!

Comment: Ich gebrauche das durchaus (ist somit nur anekdotische Evidenz). Die erste Variante legt den Schluss nahe, dass es genau zwei Binärzahlen gibt, 01 und 10.

Comment: Uns mangelt es halt leider an einem distributiver Plural :) Aus dem Grund tendiere ich auch viel mehr zur zweiten Variante. Hinzufügen möchte ich noch die übliche Ergänzung, dass es in Österreich eher _Nuller und Einser_ heißen würde.